# ImagePickerController not correctly positioned in View

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

after I implemented the ImagePickerController into one of my viewControllers and put that into my TabController I got the following effect when launching. Everything works fine so far.. but.... look at the view:

[image: ImagePickercontroller]

Thats the code I just implemented therefore:

```
- (void)loadView{
    self.arController = [[IFAugmentRealityController alloc] initWithViewController:self];
    [self showCamera];
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.picker.view];
}
```

The frame is set.. but how do I get rid of the black bar between the picker and the tabbar?

Thank you!!

[UIImagePickerController in TabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010105/uiimagepickercontroller-in-tabbarcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.. Just got it... here is my solution:
The black bar is due to a difference in size ratio between the camera and the screen. You can fix this by transforming the camera very slightly:

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = transform;

The result is a full screen camera image! It is ever so slightly bigger but it’s not noticeable unless you put it side by side with a non transformed version.